# Fopen function returns null when given an existing path

Tags: c, fopen

When trying to open a file with `fopen(path, "2");` i get NULL on an existing path

iv'e tried to enter only the file name and it works but i want the program to write the file in the path...
Yes, i write the path with double backslashes `"\\"` when it's necesary.
Yes the path without doubt exists.

```
FILE* log;
char directory_path[PATH_LEN] = { 0 };
char directory_file[PATH_LEN] = { 0 };

//directory_path is the directory, entered by  the user
//LOG_NAME is the files name without the path - "log.txt"
//#define PATH_LEN 100

printf("Folder to scan:  ");
fgets(directory_path, PATH_LEN, stdin);
directory_path[strlen(directory_path) - 1] = 0;

//this section connects the path with the file name.
strcpy(directory_file, directory_path);
strcat(directory_file, "\\");
strcat(directory_file, LOG_NAME);

if ((log = fopen(directory_file, "w")) == NULL)
{
    printf("Error");
}
```

My program worked until i tried to write into a file in order to create a log file. This means that the path is correct without doubt.

Can anyone tell me the problem here?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Maybe a problem of access rights. You should use perror() to have a meaningful error message.

Comment: I edited my code sample so you can see what im doing

Comment: @AlainMerigot i'm getting a premission denied error. but i can open other files in the same folder using fopen

Comment: What folder name did you enter?

Comment: Look at the file permissions in your folder. It may also be a problem of spelling.

Comment: Also, check if the file is read-only.

Comment: If you need more info, you can check `errno` to possibly get more data on why `fopen()` failed.  I would for sure print to console what the path was (or verify in debugger) just to be sure.  I'm always surprised by what gets passed into strings when i don't verify.

Comment: Always check the return value of fgets(): if (fgets(...) == NULL) /* indeterminate array */ (Copy Pasta from another comment, but valid reminder here.)

Comment: regarding: `printf("Error");`  The code should use: `perror( "fopen to write failed" );`  So both your error message And The text reason the system thinks the error occurred are output to `stderr`

Comment: OT: regarding: `directory_path[strlen(directory_path) - 1] = 0;`  This is a somewhat 'iffy' way to remove a trailing newline.  Suggest: `directory_path[ strcspn( directory_path, "\n") ] = '\0';`

Comment: regarding; `char directory_path[PATH_LEN] = { 0 };
char directory_file[PATH_LEN] = { 0 };`  The array: `directory_file[]` should be longer than the array: `directory_path[]` to allow room for the `\\` and the length of the string: "log.txt"  I.E. it should be another 8 (or 9) bytes longer

Comment: regarding the text in your question: `fopen(path, "2");`  This will NEVER work.  The second argument must be a valid "mode"

Comment: @user3629249 I suggest posting this in an answer instead of filling up the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues in your code:

For one, `fopen(path, "2");` is not valid.
The `mode` argument needs to include one of `a`, `r`, and `w` and can optionally include `b` or `+`.

As another thing, `directory_path[strlen(directory_path) - 1] = 0;` may truncate the end of your path (if it's over `PATH_LEN` characters long).

There also may be a possible issue with buffer overflow due to the fact that you copy a string to a buffer of the same size and then concatenate two other strings to it. Therefore, you should change this line:

```
char directory_file[PATH_LEN] = { 0 };
```

to this:

```
char directory_file[PATH_LEN+sizeof(LOG_NAME)+1] = { 0 };
```

To debug this issue, you should print the string entered and ask for confirmation before using it (wrap this in `#ifdef DEBUG`).

Comment: regarding: `As another thing, fgets automatically null terminates strings. As such, directory_path[strlen(directory_path) - 1] = 0; is not needed. It may truncate the end of your path`  not quite true.  The OP was trying to replace the trailing newline (as read by `fgets()`) with a NUL byte

Comment: regarding: `char directory_file[PATH_LEN+sizeof(LOG_NAME)+1] = { 0 };`  The `sizeof()` will return the length of a pointer.  The statement should be: `char directory_file[PATH_LEN+strlen(LOG_NAME)+1] = { 0 };`

Comment: @user3629249 Updated. How does that look?

Comment: @user3629249 No, it will return the size of the string (including the terminating null byte) plus one character (for the backslash path separator). That's the minimum amount needed to store the largest possible path entered.

Comment: the expression: `sizeof(LOG_NAME)` degrades to the address of the `LOG_NAME` so it returns a pointer, not the number of bytes in the string

Comment: @user3629249 Read up on `sizeof`: If it's passed an array (which a string literal just so happens to be) then it returns the size of the array.

Comment: referencing a bare array name degrades to the address of the first byte of the array, NOT the number of bytes in the array.

Comment: @user3629249 Run `sizeof("Wow, it works!")` in a program and tell me that it returns the same thing as `sizeof(char *)`. `sizeof` is not a normal function and degradation does not apply the same way to it.